# Java Android - Still getting old file

Tags: java, android, file

I'm still receiving 1st file my app generated for me.
First , I thought it's because the file exists so I wrote

```
File file=new File(getCacheDir(), "Competition.xls");
    if (file.exists()) {file.delete(); file =new File(getCacheDir(), "Competition.xls");}
```

But that didn't help me-I still receive first file that was made

I'm new to working with files so I decided to copy entire method here. Sorry for a lot of text.

```
private void createFileTosend() {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
    try {
        File toSend=null;
        try {
            toSend = getFile();
        } catch (WriteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        inputStream = new FileInputStream(toSend);


        outputStream = openFileOutput("Competition.xls",
                Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE | Context.MODE_APPEND);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length = 0;
        try {
            while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0){
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            /* ignore */
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        /* ignore */
    } finally {
        try {
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
           /* ignore */
        }
        try {
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
           /* ignore */
        }
    }
}
public File getFile()  throws IOException, WriteException{
    File file=new File(getCacheDir(), "Competition.xls");
    if (file.exists()) {file.delete(); file =new File(getCacheDir(), "Competition.xls");}

    WritableWorkbook  workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(file); 
    //then goes long block with creating a .xls file which is not important
    workbook.write();
    workbook.close(); 

    return file;
}
```

Help on understanding where the problem is

Comment: it's a copy from ActionBarSherlock's example. I'll deal with them later, now I have to do something to get the right file

Comment: obviously your file.exists() code block has some issue
try putting a sout to check whether any error in there, you might even be having File access error [since you are supressing exception you wont know]

Comment: No, you can't do that, you have to deal with them right now.

Comment: Also, you should consider using IOUtils from commons io. http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html Such a copy would take 3-4 lines and would be far less error prone.

Comment: So. Isn't anyone to help me ? I didn't get any exception on printStackTrace() and nobody said anything how to solve it

Answer (score 2):

You should never have a structure like :

```
catch(Exception ex ) {
     //ignore (or log only)
}
```

Exception are there to tell you something went wrong. What you do is called (in french) "eating/hiding exceptions". You are loosing this very important information that something went abnormally.

You should *always* either throw the exception you catch to your caller, or process it locally. At the very least, and this is a poor practice, you should log it. But doing nothing is just very wrong.

Here, put the whole try catch in a method for instance :

```
private void createFileTosend() throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
    try {
        File toSend = getFile();
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(toSend);


        outputStream = openFileOutput("Competition.xls",
                Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE | Context.MODE_APPEND);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length = 0;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0){
             outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
         }
    } finally {

        try {
            if( inputStream != null ) {
                inputStream.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
           Log.e( ioe );
        }
        try {
            if( outputStream != null ) {
                outputStream.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
           Log.e( ioe );
        }
    }
}
```

And now, when you call `createFileToSend`, do that in a try/catch structure and toast a message, or something if you catch an exception.

Comment: You are loosing information that you would use to find out the bug you have. If something bad happens, you just ignored it, will never know and will never correct it. Isn't that the case right now ?

Comment: Put in other words. Your question is "Something is going wrong, what to do ?" The answer is always : "what is going wrong ?", and you can't answer that because you swallowed all exceptions.

Comment: I put printStackTrace() everywhere but still don't get an error message

Comment: well, the issue is somewere else. it's not in the catch block. BTW, every new time my file gets bigger in size but when I open it - it's still the same

Comment: Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE | Context.MODE_APPEND

Comment: oh.. it appends to file instead of creating a new one ! Thanks a lot ! can you make an answer of that so I accept it?

Comment: But this is answer ;)

Comment: no, the whole issue were in MODE_APPEND flag. theese exceptions had nothing to do with my issue. The file was appended instead of rewritten so at outcome I received same old file but it's size were bigger every time.

Comment: Ok, so I didn't find the answer to your problem directly. I am nevertheless glad to have contributed to the robustness of your code and your understanding of exceptions in Java. That's fine for me, no need to trick SOF to get more points, your understanding is already a precious rewarding jewel ;) . Thx for the proposal anyway.

Comment: well, honestly, I still have no idea how to deal with log of IO exceptions with internal memory. If it's with SD card - ok, we may not have sd card or it is full or anything else. But it's the internal file. And once again, it's not my code, it's slightly modified ActionBarSherlock's example